# where to store program registration information

Tags: .net, registry

I have created a program with a 30 day trial period in VB.Net. The program saves the time in the registry that the program was first launched and also the time is was used last. From that I calculate if the trial is still valid.

The problem is, the only place in the registry that a non-admin user can access is the HKEY_LOCAL_USER key. I need to implement the trial for all users, otherwise a user can just use a new account and that would reset the trial.

Where can I save this information so that a user without admin rights can read and write from that location? I also want to save it in a place that the average user can't find too easily and delete the file that would reset the trial.

Thanks

Comment: A user could also simply delete the value. That's easier than using a new account.

Comment: how about storing the data both in HKEY_LOCAL_USER and in a file in application data directory? If it's already in the file, when the app's started copy that to HKEY_LOCAL_USER.

Comment: I just want to save it in a place that the average guy won't be able to find. I know it's impossible to stop a user from using the program for free if he really wants to. The average user of my program won't be able to delete the key from the registry. So, what do you suggest is the best place to save this data that is available to all users (admin and non-admin), and not that easy to find

Comment: @kenny. Thanks, that sounds like a good solution. Where can I save it so that it is common to all user? I know I can use Environment.GetFolderPath(  Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)), but that is once again unique for all users.

Comment: @Johan, yes, I think that's the one that shared between all users and for 'applications'.

Comment: I just checked, and if I use Environment.GetFolderPath( Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) then I still can't read files in there if the user does not admin rights. Are there no place where I can share files between non-Admin users?? I'm using Win 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was actually where to save data that all users can access (read and write).

In Win 7 this can get tricky. I found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/tips/61987/Allow-write-modify-access-to-CommonApplicationData.aspx) article on code project that explains how this can be achieved for folders.

I then read a file and save values in the registry as suggested by Kenny above.

If somebody has a better method, please share it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure anyone has found a definitive answer for this. The only way is to store the data with you and not with the client - so do a web call on installation, and on every startup, and store the data on your server.

Which, unless you have an especially serious problem, is very OTT.

Short of that, encrypt and save the information on a file in the install directory. Encrypting it should make sure that the value cannot be changed, and if the file does not exist then do not allow access.

But it all depends how critical the trial period is.

Comment: The install directory is Program files and if the user does not have admin rights he would not be able to save data there. As I said above, I need a place where a non-admin user can save files that can be accessed by all users of the PC. And yes, doing a web call is not an option for me.

Comment: @Johan - He must be able to write to that folder, or he wouldn't be able to install your program in the first place. As long as you set the date as part of the installation process, you're fine.

Comment: An admin may have installed the application. So that is not an option. Could you use c:\? Not generally a good idea, but it should be accessible, and there is precious little that you know shoudl be accessible.

Comment: What if I use Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)? Is that accessible to all users? I will then copy the data to HKEY_LOCAL_USER as Kenny suggested above. I must save the time the program was used last to check that the user simply doesn't change the time.

Comment: I just checked, and if I use Environment.GetFolderPath( Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) then I still can't read files in there if the user does not have admin rights. Does anybody know of a place where I can save files so that all users can read/write it?

Comment: If anyone uses the remote server idea, youwould also want to use SSL or some such to talk to the server, else the user could sniff the traffic and make a fake "good" response from the server.

Answer (score 1):

Save the needed data in binary (`DateTime.Now.Ticks` is `System.Int64` ;) ) and inflate it with redundant data and make a checksum field. On load check the checksum field and if it is wrong-the data has been tampered with so kill the trial period. You could also save the data in a file next to your application to avoid using the registry ( both for cross-platform compatibility and avoiding the required admin privileges )

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE is for all users but the user installing your app must have admin privileges.